# List of function I want to Mock. Mocking function. Pytest

Tags: python, pytest, python-decorators, pytest-mock

I have a list of functions that return Boolean values.
It's all called like this:

```
for f in functions:
    if f():
        pass
```

I am writing tests and I want to mock the result of those functions

```
@pytest.fixture
def is_first_func_mock(mocker):
    mock = mocker.patch.object(SomeClass, 'first_func')
    return mock
```

and then somewhere in the test I pass this fixture and write
`is_first_func_mock.return_value = True` or something like that

But since I'm not calling the function directly in the code, and since I indicated it above, the mock does not work.

I found a solution in Stackoverflow:
I can call functions like that:

```
if getattr(funcs_module, func.__name__)():
    pass
```

But I don't like it and I don't want to change the loop

Update:

```
def some_name(fucntions: list[callable]):
    def inner(func):
        @wraps(func)
        async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            #some code
            for f in functions:
                if f():
                    return await func(*args, **kwargs)
            raise SomePermission

        return wrapper

    return inner
```

Comment: Where does the list `functions` come from? Can you inject a list of stubs instead?

Comment: @quamrana I have a function that takes in a list of functions. And this list can be different

Comment: Perhaps you could show more code around where `functions` comes from and the function that contains the for loop over them.

Comment: I see you have added a new function. That looks like a decorator. It has the line: `def inner(func):` Have you accidentally aliased the variable `func`? Did you mean to write: `for f in functions: if f(): return await func ... `?

Comment: @quamrana oh sorry, yes, of course, I mean 'for f in functions'. I copied this from my code and changed it a little bit. I'll edit a question again.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are doing. I presume that you decorate some functions like this: `@some_name(functions) ...` That means that `functions` is decided before the functions are defined. Is that right?

Comment: @quamrana Yes, in code I call it: `@has_any_permissions([is_admin, is_users_moderator])
async def about_user(): pass`

Comment: So, surely you can just mock, say, `is_admin` to return `True`.

Comment: @quamrana could you show me how, please? Because everything I tried doesn't work correctly

Comment: Please update your question with the sample function that you decorate. It is more difficult to decorate when the function is bound in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to find a solution, but here is a workaround:

```py
from functools import wraps

def has_any_permissions(get_functions):
    def inner(func):
        @wraps(func)
        async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # some code
            funcs = get_functions()
            if any(f() for f in funcs):
                return await func(*args, **kwargs)
            raise SomePermission()

        return wrapper
    return inner

def is_admin():
    return False

def is_users_moderator():
    return False

def admin_and_users_moderator():
    return [is_admin, is_users_moderator]

@has_any_permissions(admin_and_users_moderator)
def about_user():
    return 'user'   # just for demonstration purposes
```

I have had to introduce some indirection where the decorator does not bind the actual list of functions at decoration time, but instead supplies a function which, when called inside `wrapper()` gets the functions each time the target could be called.

The corresponding unit test might look like this:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from mockable_functions import about_user

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_plain_function_raises(self):
        self.assertRaises(SomePermission, about_user)

    @patch('mockable_functions.is_admin')
    def test_func(self, is_admin_mock):
        is_admin_mock.return_value = True
        self.assertEqual(about_user(), 'user', 'about_user returns user')
```

This unit test shows that `about_user()` raises an error when called normally, but when the `is_admin` function is patched, then the real function gets called (and returns a dummy value)